# Running post build event from macro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have few projects in my solution, MVC applications which does some copying, those are static files like stylesheet, scripts etc. so I need a way to run it without having to build project every time I change something. My post build action uses variables like `$(SolutionDir)`

Is it possible to run post build event from macro?

Comment: Maybe you can convert your post build action to an External Tools action (it can also use environment variables).

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Good idea, so I just put it in a batch, register it as external tool then call external tool from macro and from post build event?

Comment: Yes, I think you can call external tool from a keyboard shortcut/menu and call batch from post build event.