# Can you create a macro or similar to run the post build events in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a post build event that compiles some CSS. It runs when I build my solution. However building my solution takes a few seconds, and when I am doing frequent CSS changes having to build the entire solution every time is a pain.

Is there a way to run only the post build stuff without building the solution via a macro or similar? The command it runs includes the `$projectDir` which makes creating a batch file feel unclean as I'm hardcoding that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a common css language which might be supported in VS Web Essentials http://vswebessentials.com/features/less ? This will compile on save.

Comment: I am using LESS but I store my LESS in a file per page, and a couple of general files for overall styles. The post build command compiles all of it into a single .less file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892069/running-post-build-event-from-macro

Comment: Hah cool, someone asked almost the exact thing as me. No concrete answers on it though :(